# How to list/enemurate all sofwares and related .exe installed on a Windows Computer in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

As a component of an application, I have to develop in c++ a way to list all the software installed on a windows computer. In order to execute them, I need to have their related executables. (Example: Opera => opera.exe).
At this stage I have been able to look in the registry in:
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and found several softwares (not all of them)
So here's my questions:
- How can I have all the software installed on the computer? (Did I miss a registry folder?)
- How can I define the good .exe related to each software?

Comment: This is a better question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: what are you trying to do? I think there is no standard way of doing that.

Comment: You don't.  I own my own computer, I control it, and I do whatever I want.  One of the things I want is to install an application that doesn't show up on your list.  Since I'm the superuser/administrator, I win.  If you want the list of applications that the admin intends you to see, try reading the shortcuts in the Start Menu.

Comment: There is no requirement that installed software be registered anywhere. For example, [XCOPY deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment) installs software simply by using the XCOPY command.

Comment: Stackoverflow needs an option for "This entire concept is flawed"

Answer (score 3):

You could try to adapt the script given here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156540.aspx

In general, use WMI to find installed packages. Or simply traverse the filesystem to look for executables if you really want to find all executable files on the system (why?).

For C++ you might want to have a look at the examples for WMI Win32_Product and SoftwareFeature. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx

But in general, there is no sane way to find all installed applications. Especially not if you count things like webpages with embedded javascript, all kind of scripts and batch files etc. etc.

Comment: Basically, My main application will provide a GUI to launch any software installed on the computer. That's why I really to know which executable to launch for each applications.

Comment: Well, if you really only care for properly 'installed' applications, go for the WMI Methods illustrated in the article.